# How to code "git commit" in libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

I have searched Google and Stackoverflow for an answer to the question of how to code the equivalent of
    git commit -a -m "message"
in libgit2 (https://libgit2.github.com) and C or C++.
But I cannot find a ready and working answer to this question.
I am using libgit2-0.21.

Below is code that initializes a git repository, adds two files to it, and stages the two files so they are ready to be committed.

My question is how to code "git commit -a -m "msg" in libgit2?

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <git2.h>
using namespace std;


int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  git_threads_init ();

  // Create repository directory.
  string directory = "repository";
  mkdir (directory.c_str(), 0777);

  // Initialize the repository: git init.
  git_repository *repo = NULL;
  int result = git_repository_init (&repo, directory.c_str(), false);
  if (result != 0) cerr << giterr_last ()->message << endl;

  // Store two files in the repository directory.
  ofstream file;
  file.open ("repository/file1", ios::binary | ios::trunc);
  file << "Contents of file one";
  file.close ();

  file.open ("repository/file2", ios::binary | ios::trunc);
  file << "Contents of file two";
  file.close ();

  // Run the equivalent of "git add ."

  // Get the git index.
  git_index * index = NULL;
  result = git_repository_index (&index, repo);
  if (result != 0) cerr << giterr_last ()->message << endl;

  // Add all files to the git index.
  result = git_index_add_all (index, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
  if (result != 0) cerr << giterr_last ()->message << endl;

  // Write the index to disk.
  result = git_index_write (index);
  if (result != 0) cerr << giterr_last ()->message << endl;

  // Run the equivalent of "git commit -a -m "commit message".

  // How to do that through libgit2?


  // Run "git status" to see the result.
  system ("cd repository; git status");

  // Free resources.
  git_index_free (index);
  git_repository_free (repo);
  git_threads_shutdown ();

  return 0;
}
```

The code can be compiled as follows:

```
g++ -Wall -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lgit2 -o test git.cpp
```

Below is the output of running the compiled binary:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   file1
    new file:   file2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the index is updated

- create a tree from it through `git_index_write_tree()`
- create a commit that references this tree through `git_commit_create_v()`

See this end to end **[test](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/091165c53b2bcd5d41fb71d43ed5a23a3d96bf5d/tests/object/commit/commitstagedfile.c#L21-L134)** which performs the equivalent of the following

```
 $ echo "test" > test.txt
 $ git add .
 $ git commit -m "Initial commit"
```